# Query ToList() returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

**Class**

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public bool Employed { get; set; }
    public bool Administrator { get; set; }
}
```

**Linq statement**

```
var adminlist = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Administrator).Select(x => x.Administrator).ToList();
```

I'm sure this is a stupid question but please can anybody tell me why the above returns null? I've tried this too:

```
var adminlist = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Administrator).ToList();
```

Comment: Are there any employees with `Administrator==true`?

Comment: Haha - yes there are. I'm not *quite* that stupid! This also returns null: var adminlist = db.Employees.Where(x => !x.Administrator).Select(x => x.Administrator).ToList();

Comment: Are you using EF Code First?, how did you add `Employee` records to your `Employees` table? The `Initializer`, directly into your table?, Add controller?

Comment: Yes - exactly as you say. I assumed I had a syntax error because there is no obvious problem with any of the tables

Comment: What does `var test = adminlist == null;` give?

Comment: There is no reason your (especially second) queries would return null. The second query should return an empty list (if there are no entries where (Administrator == true)).

Comment: Thanks folks. I've just rebooted and the statement is now returning the correct result. God knows what happened there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your second query will NEVER return null unless the database is inaccessible. [`IEnumerable.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) will never return `null`, only an empty list if no items were found. It will throw an exception if the *source* is null.

Your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Should be sure that all fields that you defined as nullable are sync with the entity, e.g. Imagine Surname is nullable in DB then will raise "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public bool Employed { get; set; }
    public bool Administrator { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it turns out i had not saved the changes on my table. Hence was returning null/empty

Comment: Don't know if this is relevant (or if this holds for boolean values), but I've seen a null-*exception* (not a null *instance*) on ToList() whenever I use EF6 linq to retrieve double fields which are left NULL in my SqLite-database. It does *not* crash for string fields that are left NULL.

Comment: .. and I solved it using nullable types in the model declaration (question mark syntax)